# To display long text area comments in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a long text area comment given as input by user. In order that it should be properly wrapped in my JSP, I'm using the below code. `commentarea` is my text area:

```
function addNewlines(commentarea) {
    
  var result = '';
  while ($.trim(commentarea).length > 0) {
    result += $.trim(commentarea).replace(/[\s\n\r]+/g, ' ').substring(0, 40) + '\n'; commentarea= $.trim(commentarea).replace(/[\s\n\r]+/g, ' ').substring(40);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The text is getting wrapped but the problem is I'm getting white spaces between words that are at 40 character length. For example, in my output I'm getting a space between
`prog rammable` and `sim ple`

> hello world today this is a simple prog rammable hello world today this is a sim ple prog rammable

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing that inside a while loop ?

Comment: yes else i will not get entire sentence

Comment: @tina, Please add more precisions as it seems we all failed to understand your question properly. From what I have seen in your code, I saw an attempt to remove all multiple spaces and line breaks from the and solutions already have been provided for that. If this is not what you are trying to achieve, try explaining in a different way. Thanks!

Comment: ok lets consider this add commenting zone in stackoverflow now if i paste a long comment like

Comment: qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwiujjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhswwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: it does not wraps in my jsp and my jsp gets distorted :) thats why i was using \n code but what happens in that code is for the above comment example it wrks fine

Comment: but if i give a comment like

Comment: hello world today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap hello world today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap hello world today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap hello world today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap

Comment: hello world today this is a simple progr ammable code which can used to wrap hell o world today this is a simple programma ble code which can used to wrap hello wo rld today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap hello world today this is a simple programmable code which can used to wrap

Comment: u can see the unnecessary space at  progr ammable,hell o,wo rld

Comment: @tina, Ok I get what you mean, however when you say "in my jsp", what do you mean exactly? Do you display the text inside a `div` and it's not getting wrapped properly? For text wrapping inside the `textarea`, using the `wrap` attribute should work. I know why your solution is not working and I know how to solve it with a similar approach, but we first need to see if you have to do it this way ;)

Comment: i tried using wrap attribbute but its giving invalid attribute error jsp means my frontend jsp where i show the data entered in textarea by user, once entered i fetch the text area data from database...

Comment: any ideas still badly stuck!!!!

Answer (score 1):

orelse you better to use 'word-wrap' instead of that....refer this
[**This**](http://www.idocs.com/tags/forms/_TEXTAREA_WRAP.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loops to replace all spaces and line breaks by a single space.

```
commentarea.value = commentarea.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').substring(0, 40);
```

Comment: how will i get entire sentence if i dunt  use loops

Comment: @tina, what do you mean by "get the entire sentence"? `commentarea.value` contains the whole content of the `textarea`. You don't have to `split` the content into sentences and process them individually only to strip line breaks and multiple spaces, unless there's something I did not understand in what you are trying to achieve.